# return collection of ArrayList from a constructor

Tags: java, arraylist, getter-setter

This beginner homework of mine requires create a method named getStudentsByMajor (String major).

This method returns a collection(ArrayList) of students whose majoring in major.

Here is my progress so far :

```
    private String courseName;
    private String roomNumber;
    private String Lecturer;
    private ArrayList <Student> studentList;

    public LectureRoom(String roomNumber , String courseName , String Lecturer)
    {

        this.courseName=courseName;
        this.roomNumber=roomNumber;
        this.Lecturer = Lecturer;
        this.studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
    }

    public void addStudent(String name, String id, String major)
    {
        Student s = new Student(name, id , major);
        studentList.add(s);
    }

    public ArrayList<Student> getStudentsByMajor(String major)
    {

    }
```

(Part of the question details)
Hint:

```
public ArrayList<Student> getStudentsByMajor(String major)
```

More hint:

```
for(ElementType element: collection){
    loop body;
    }
```

Learning setter and getter, I understand that whenever the word "getter" is there, there is usually no parameter.

What I think would work is something like:

```
public ArrayList<Student> getStudentsByMajor(String major)
        {
            for( Student a : studentList)
            {
                System.out.println(major)
            }
        }
```

Obviously it's wrong but I hope I can get some pointers here.

Comment: `getStudentsByMajor()` is not a constructor as your title says.

Comment: Try youself what you think will work!! If you issues then you can come here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public ArrayList<Student> getStudentsByMajor(String major)
{
    ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Student student : studentList) {
        if (student.getMajor().equals(major))
            students.add(student);
    }

    return students;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It made a lot of sense with what RC wrote. As mentioned what I needed was to create another fresh list of empty student.

Answer (score 3):

In `getStudentsByMajor`:

1. creates a fresh list of student (empty)
2. iterates over existing students (`studentList`)
3. for each student check major
4. if major ok add to the new list
5. return the new list